# Corda - IOU demo doesn't work on Windows

Tags: kotlin, corda

I've just cloned a new copy of the [Corda V1.0 IOU](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example) demo and tried to run it on Windows 10, resulting in this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java" (in directory
>   "C:\Repos\Corda\CordaDemoApp\build\20171006122614\PartyA"):
>   CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by shortening the path by installing the JDK at the root of the drive (e.g. at c:\jdk-1.8.0_131), and pointing IntelliJ at that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows use the subst command to substitute a path to a drive letter, for example:

subst b: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre"

Now update your JAVA_HOME environment variable to be:

JAVA_HOME = B:\

You'll need to restart your terminal window for the new environment variable to take effect.